# Ubuntu 18.04 Where are window positions stored when an app closes, so that they can be opened in the same place after restarting

Tags: 18.04, windows

When an application such as firefox opens the window is positioned in the same place as when it closed (i.e half of the screen to the left or to the right etc.), which is a useful feature.

Where is this information stored? I would like to be able to view this flag in the terminal and potentially be able to change it via the command line or change it so that it always opens in the same place.

Thanks

Comment: At least in Kubuntu, the window size and placement is stored in application-specific files.

Comment: please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Install GNOME extension `Put Windows`. Find it [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/).

- Fully customizable replacement for the old compiz put plugin.
- Move windows to left/right side, bottom/top, center or corner
- Move window to other screen
- Select focused window using the keyboard
- Application based window placement